# oracle SQL procedure distinct output

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I just started with PL/SQL, so, please be kind. I have a simple problem. I want to extract distinct names phoneNo and address, it's cars and customers entities

**this is the code that I use:**

```
create or replace procedure customer_info ( p_customerid customer.customerid%type)
as
cursor executive is
select  customername, address, phoneno, regno, carmodel, color, plateno
from customer c, car car
where c.customerid = p_customerid
and  c.customerid = car.customerid;

begin

for v_loop in executive loop

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Customer name:  ' || v_loop.customername);
dbms_output.put_line ('Customer Address:  ' || v_loop.address);
dbms_output.put_line ('Customer Phone Number:  ' || v_loop.phoneno);
dbms_output.put_line ('Car registiration number:  ' || v_loop.regno);
dbms_output.put_line ('Car model:  ' || v_loop.carmodel);
dbms_output.put_line ('Car color:  ' || v_loop.color);
dbms_output.put_line ('Car plate number:  ' || v_loop.plateno);
    end loop;
END customer_info;
/
```

**what I get is this output:**

```
Customer name:  ahmed
Customer Address:  jeddah
Customer Phone Number:  538447169
Car registiration number:  car101
Car model:  mg5
Car color:  gray
Car plate number:  KSA 5808
Customer name:  ahmed
Customer Address:  jeddah
Customer Phone Number:  538447169
Car registiration number:  car113
Car model:  rio
Car color:  black
Car plate number:  ksa 5909
```

**what I want the output to be is**

```
Customer name:  ahmed
Customer Address:  jeddah
Customer Phone Number:  538447169
Car registiration number:  car101
Car model:  mg5
Car color:  gray
Car plate number:  KSA 5808
Car registiration number:  car113
Car model:  rio
Car color:  black
Car plate number:  ksa 5909
```

Comment: It's hard to read your outputs, please format it properly.  Also, to clarify your question, do you mean you mean a unique combination of names phoneNo and address and return all cars and customers entities of said combination of columns?

Comment: now I edit it, what I want is to output the customer name, phone number and address. and to show also all cars he owns with car details like it shown in the output

Comment: You would need two loops (and two SQL statements). An outer loop to go process the customers and an inner loop to process each customer's cars

Answer (score 0):

```
     create or replace procedure customer_info ( p_customerid 
       customer.customerid%type) as
     cursor executive is
     select  customername, address, phoneno, regno, carmodel, 
       color, plateno
     from customer c, car car
     where c.customerid = p_customerid
       and  c.customerid = car.customerid;
     v_first number:=1;
   begin
     for v_loop in executive loop
       if v_fisrt=1 then
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Customer name:  ' || v_loop.customername);
         dbms_output.put_line ('Customer Address:  ' || v_loop.address);
         dbms_output.put_line ('Customer Phone Number:  ' || v_loop.phoneno);
         v_first:=v_first-1;
       end if;
       dbms_output.put_line ('Car registiration number:  ' || v_loop.regno);
       dbms_output.put_line ('Car model:  ' || v_loop.carmodel);
       dbms_output.put_line ('Car color:  ' || v_loop.color);
       dbms_output.put_line ('Car plate number:  ' || v_loop.plateno);
     end loop;
  END customer_info;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to aggregate data in PL/SQL... do it in SQL. Just add DISTINCT to your cursor:

```
create or replace procedure customer_info ( p_customerid customer.customerid%type)
as
cursor executive is
select  DISTINCT customername, address, phoneno, regno, carmodel, color, plateno
from customer c, car car
where c.customerid = p_customerid
and  c.customerid = car.customerid;

begin

for v_loop in executive loop

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Customer name:  ' || v_loop.customername);
dbms_output.put_line ('Customer Address:  ' || v_loop.address);
dbms_output.put_line ('Customer Phone Number:  ' || v_loop.phoneno);
dbms_output.put_line ('Car registiration number:  ' || v_loop.regno);
dbms_output.put_line ('Car model:  ' || v_loop.carmodel);
dbms_output.put_line ('Car color:  ' || v_loop.color);
dbms_output.put_line ('Car plate number:  ' || v_loop.plateno);
    end loop;
END customer_info;
/
```